# Is using *Our mind remembers* wrong English?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

I said to my teacher-"Our mind remembers...". He said this is wrong and the correct is-"our minds remember...". I told him that if we keep the verb as 'remembers' my statement seems correct. But he said I am wrong. But I don't understand why. Is this really incorrect?

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: *Our mind* would refer to a mind that both you and I share. But we don't share a mind. We each have our own mind. This means that *mind* should be plural (that is, *minds*). Unless, of course, you believe in the collective consciousness!

Comment: It would require an unusual context to justify *My mind remembers...* rather than the standard ***I** remember...*

Comment: Yes: The science fair came down to two teams; each had developed a synthetic mind that was supposed to be capable of retaining information.  The winning team captain was asked how they were able to defeat the other team.  He responded, "Our mind remembers."

Comment: Using "Our potato remembers" is not "incorrect English".  Whether it makes logical sense is a separate issue.

Comment: @Jim - So why did you respond "yes" to the question?

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I'm sure I've heard "My mind remembers ..." a number of times, from reasonably literate speakers/writers.  It's a poetic form, but the syntax requires no poetic license.

Comment: @HotLicks - My mind forgets, it looks it it got confused though. My intent appears to have been to show how that sentence *could* be correct in the proper context, but I’m guessing that was not OP’s context.

Answer (score 1):

"Our mind remembers" sounds okay to me.  I understand it as an impersonal, which could alternatively be expressed "one's mind remembers", but this impersonal "one" sounds old-fashioned and rather stiff.  Using "we/our" impersonally is more natural in current-day English.

Comment: My teacher preferred The mind remembers....i don't know why...

Comment: He preferred Our over The...

Comment: I agree. In the right context, it's the same as discussing any generic trait. "Our opposable thumb enables us to grasp tools" doesn't mean there's a single thumb that all humanity is somehow attached to...